# Can Gulp add a custom CSS?

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Price Tracker</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <!-- bower:css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <!-- endbower -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- bower:js -->
        <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-css/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- endbower -->
    </body>
</html>
```

My `gulpfile` picks up the bower dependencies correctly and adds them to the index. But I want gulp to pick up a custom CSS file.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Did the answers below not provide a solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can embed any CSS file path you want, this is what I'm using [**htmlReplace**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace)

https://github.com/VFK/gulp-html-replace

`npm install --save-dev gulp-html-replace`

---

```
// Task to make the index file production ready
var htmlReplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

gulp.task('build:index', function() {
  gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(htmlReplace({
        //'app-css' : 'assets/'+version+'/css/dashboard.css',
        'app-css' : 'assets/css/dashboard.css',
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Then in your markup

```
<!-- build:app-css -->
<!-- Anything between the build comments gets replaced --> 
<link href="dev/assets/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

---

This is how you delete files, with [**run-sequence**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence?__hstc=72727564.3f7e9b5f6baac5c3c57e5cf13b5cd4f5.1452430715595.1453511363626.1453605458153.9&__hssc=72727564.3.1453605458153&__hsfp=2401871769)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/del

```
// Clear out all files and folders from build folder:
gulp.task('build:cleanfolder', function(cb) {
    del([
        'build/**'
    ], cb);
});
```

This is how you pipe different tasks together and in order

```
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
    runSequence(
        'version',                  // Save new version
        'build:del-assets-static',  // Delete old static folder in app/assets
        'build:move-files',         // Move files into new static folder
        'html-templates',           // Generate $templateCache file of HTML partials
        //'build-highcharts-css',            // Minify and concat highcharts styles
        'build-app-css',            // Minify and concat app styles
        'highcharts-js',            // Minify and concat highcharts scripts
        'build-app-js',             // Minify and concat app scripts
        'build:copy',               // Deletes old build folder
        'build:remove',             // Copy then Remove unneeded assets from build
        'build:version',            // Move assets into versioned build folder
        'build:index',              // Replace scripts in index.html
        'build:final-clean', cb);   // Remove app.min.js from build folder
});
```

Comment: Seems to work but the file ends up in folder `build`, which is not what I'm looking for. I want the task to take `app/index.html` as source AND destination for the changes. I tried changing the `dest` but gulp whines about the file existing already.

Comment: Oh you need a task to delete that file first, I will post later

Comment: @FrancisDucharme updated my answer with how to pipe a del command, before the css replace html

Answer (score 1):

[gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) is probably what you are looking for.  It works similar to Wiredep and lets you specify where to insert css/js tags into the html for every match found (specified by [glob pattern](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#glob-primer))

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My index</title>
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->

    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
  </body>
</html>





// Gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.task('custom', function(){
    var sources = gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', './src/**/*.css'], {read: false});
    return gulp.src('./index.html')
               .pipe(inject(sources))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
})
```